# View not found for ViewModel (IWindowManager.ShowDialog) in Caliburn

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm, caliburn.micro

The problem is that when I use third Paramameter of windowManager.showDialog() function, which is settings, I get the error message that View for my ViewModel was not found.

```cs
var view = Caliburn.Micro.ViewLocator.LocateForModel(MyViewModel, null, null);
dynamic settings = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
settings.ShowInTaskbar = false;
Caliburn.Micro.ViewModelBinder.Bind(MyViewModel, view, null);
this.windowManager.ShowDialog(MyViewModel, "", settings);
```

It looks like providing the settings, View is gone. But when I remove the last two parameters, things work file. I have tries SO and other forums, but could not found an answer.

Thanks for the support in advance.
Irfan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: try to show dialog without specifying **context** parameter - leave it with it's default `null` value by leveraging [**Optional Arguments**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) introduced in **C# 4.0**:

```cs
this.windowManager.ShowDialog(MyViewModel, settings: settings);
```

Long answer: here is how method [WindowManager.ShowDialog()](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Caliburn.Micro.Silverlight/WindowManager.cs) looks like:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Shows a modal dialog for the specified model.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="rootModel">The root model.</param>
/// <param name="context">The context.</param>
/// <param name="settings">The optional dialog settings.</param>
public virtual void ShowDialog(object rootModel,
                               object context = null,
                               IDictionary<string, object> settings = null)
{
    var view = EnsureWindow(rootModel,
                           ViewLocator.LocateForModel(rootModel, null, context));

    ViewModelBinder.Bind(rootModel, view, context);

    var haveDisplayName = rootModel as IHaveDisplayName;

    if(haveDisplayName != null &&
       !ConventionManager.HasBinding(view, ChildWindow.TitleProperty))
    {
        var binding = new Binding("DisplayName") { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };
        view.SetBinding(ChildWindow.TitleProperty, binding);
    }

    ApplySettings(view, settings);

    new WindowConductor(rootModel, view);

    view.Show();
}
```

Notice that it call `EnsureWindow()` and pass **context** argument into. If you specify this argument as **string.Empty** (or **""**) it will be treated further in Caliburn implementation differently then just `null` value to find corresponding View for provided view-model.

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks Sevenate, I will check it tomorrow after going back from trip.

Comment: @Irfan, sure - when you have time.